# Positioning isn't working correctly

Tags: actionscript-3

I am making a simple puzzle game where you have 3x3 large grid and you drop puzzle pices onto the grid and it snaps into place, the problem is that i can't get the pice to snap into place.
The grid is made up of 9 squares who each have their own instance name.
The code I am trying to use won't work:

```
    if( dropTarget )
        {
            if( dropTarget.parent.name == "S6" )
            {
                GTB.x = S6.x
                GTB.y = S6.y
            }
```

GTB is the name of the puzzle pice and S6 is the name of the square.
This code doesn't work, and i get theese errors:
1119: Access of possibly undefined property x through a reference with static type String.
1119: Access of possibly undefined property x through a reference with static type Class.
1119: Access of possibly undefined property y through a reference with static type String.
1119: Access of possibly undefined property y through a reference with static type Class.

I have also foud out that I can't change the position of GTB with GTB.x =, I have to use x =

Comment: Error means that GTB does not have an x property. You'll need to show more code (eg what is GTB)

Answer (score 0):

GTB is a string, you cannot move it.

Maybe you used the name GTB multiple times, but other you should try `GTB as MovieClip.x`

And you can't use `x =` because you cannot move the stage or a class.

Can I ask you, do you know anything about actionscript-3?